# Function to list all the email templates in a system (like getDefaultTemplatesAsOptionsArray)

Tags: extensions, custom, email-templates

I am trying to list all the email templates on a Magento installation for an extension I am working on. It currently uses the getDefaultTemplatesAsOptionsArray function but that does not list any custom templates that the user has added to the system.

I have been searching around and have not been able to find a reference for a function that would provide this.

Answer (score 2):

Create the file in NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\System\Config\Source

```
<?php
class NameSpace_ModuelName_Model_System_Config_Source_Customtemplate
{
/**
 * Config xpath to email template node
 *
 */
const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_EMAIL = 'global/template/email/';
/**
 * Generate list of email templates
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $result = array();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/email_template_collection')
        ->load();
    $options = $collection->toOptionArray();
    $defOptions = Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::getDefaultTemplatesAsOptionsArray();
    foreach ($defOptions as $v) {
        $options[] = $v;
    }
    foreach ($options as $v) {
        $result[$v['value']] = $v['label'];
    }
    // sort by names alphabetically
    asort($result);
    if (!$asHash) {
        $options = array();
        $options[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => '---------Choose Email Template---------');
        foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == '')
                continue;
            $options[] = array('value' => $k, 'label' => $v);
        }

        $result = $options;
    }
    return $result;
}
}
?>
```

And in system.xml file in field tag you have to write below code.

```
 <customtemplate translate="label">
     <label>Choose Email Template</label>
     <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                                            <source_model>modulename/system_config_source_customtemplate</source_model>
     <sort_order>40</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </customtemplate>
```

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but just for reference: there is no need to create a custom source model for email templates. Just use `adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template`, provided in Magento core. (Also, this answer isn't actually relevant to the original question, which wasn't asking about admin config.)